# MySQL how to get Month and Year with separation like date format

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

I have "datetime" field on my database,
but what I want is only take YEAR-MONTH e.g ("2012-02")

I've tried using function YEAR_MONTH but the output without "-" which is similar like "201202".

Is there any way I could make that select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to give False in second Param in Select

```
select("DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m') AS dated_now", FALSE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to specify how to format your columns:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(my_datetime_field, '%Y-%m')
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: the result only 14-07

Comment: I used the two digit notation (`%y`) instead of the four digit notation (`%Y`) by mistake - fixed.

Comment: oke its work fine in phpmyadmin, but it gets error I implement in Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y %m');
```

You can also check the below link

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
```